# Binding SOAP header with the actual data which is passed in the webservice method which is called

Tags: java, webservice-client, soapheader

I need to post jobs in monster.com by using their web service.
I  have genarated the client files using `wsimport`.
I am calling `updateJob` method which accepts `<Job>` type object.
The client files have dedicated classes for SOAP headers, in which I am 
setting the required username and password.
But I have no idea how do bind this `Header` object in my request, as the method 
I am calling only accepts `<job>` type objects.

The dedicated objects which constitute soap headers are being populated as follows

```
    MonsterHeader monsterHeader=new MonsterHeader();
    MessageDataType MessageDataType=new MessageDataType();
    MessageDataType.setMessageId("Company Jobs created on 06/09/2004 02:41:44 PM");
    MessageDataType.setTimestamp("2004-06-09T14:41:44Z");
    monsterHeader.setMessageData(MessageDataType);

    Security security=new Security();
    UsernameTokenType UsernameTokenType=new UsernameTokenType();
    UsernameTokenType.setUsername("testxftp");
    PasswordType PasswordType=new PasswordType();
    PasswordType.setValue("ftp12345");
    UsernameTokenType.setPassword(PasswordType);
```

The method which is being called is `businessGatewayInterface.updateJob(job);`

Also , please advise on some easy way to view my outgoing SOAP request.

Comment: One usually uses SOAPHandler for manipulating SOAPHeader

Comment: please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522931/how-to-add-header-to-soap-request/14523921#14523921