# Consuming SOAP webservice in java with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am trying to consume the webservice from the wsdl link where i have created and tested the link in SOAP UI software, it works fine.

But, when i am testing in eclipse getting an invalid\expired token while debugging got to know that "key" which is available in header information need to be passed.

Can anybody help how to bind the SOAP header information while retrieving the data from webservice.

This is my wsdl definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider" xmlns:intf="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider">
  <wsdl:types>
 <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider">
  <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" /> 
 <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_int">
 <complexContent>
 <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
  <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]" /> 
  </restriction>
  </complexContent>
  </complexType>
 <complexType name="ArrayOfArrayOf_soapenc_string">
 <complexContent>
 <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
  <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="soapenc:string[][]" /> 
  </restriction>
  </complexContent>
  </complexType>
 <complexType name="HeaderInfo">
 <sequence>
  <element name="LoginToken" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </sequence>
  </complexType>
  </schema>
  </wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="HeaderInfoMsg">
  <wsdl:part name="HeaderInfoPart" type="impl:HeaderInfo" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="loadTimesheetDataResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="loadTimesheetDataReturn" type="soapenc:string" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="loadTimesheetDataRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="a_psNo" type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="a_weekStartDate" type="soapenc:string" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:operation name="loadTimesheetData" parameterOrder="a_psNo a_weekStartDate">
  <wsdl:input message="impl:loadTimesheetDataRequest" name="loadTimesheetDataRequest" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="impl:loadTimesheetDataResponse" name="loadTimesheetDataResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:binding name="TSProviderSoapBinding" type="impl:TSProvider">
  <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
 <wsdl:operation name="loadTimesheetData">
  <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" /> 
 <wsdl:input name="loadTimesheetDataRequest">
  <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.servicecomp.arun.com" use="encoded" /> 
  <wsdlsoap:header encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.servicecomp.arun.com" use="encoded" message="impl:HeaderInfoMsg" part="HeaderInfoPart" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output name="loadTimesheetDataResponse">
  <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider" use="encoded" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="TSProviderService">
 <wsdl:port binding="impl:TSProviderSoapBinding" name="TSProvider">
  <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis/services/TSProvider" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522931/how-to-add-header-to-soap-request

Comment: When i provide the input of a_psNo and a_weekStartDate, i should fetch all the details mentioned in the method name "loadTimesheetData" with LoginToken which is hardcoded..